# Event ID - PRE and POST Window - in R

Tags: r, events, dplyr, cumsum, magrittr

I am conducting an event study with the market model. There are several events per ISIN. There is an event, if "Rating_Change" is "non-zero". What I need is an "ID" for each event per ISIN and also for the pre-window and post window of the event data.
It would be ideal to have per event one ID to identify also the pre and post event windows which should be -2:+2 (here in the example, in "real" it should be -5:+5).

At the moment I tried this....:

```
testing1 <- testing %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>%
  mutate(event=cumsum(Rating_Change!=0 & !is.na(Rating_Change)))
```

... and received the following output:

```
   Date         ISIN    R        STOXX_Return   Rating_Change   Rating      event
   <date>       <fct>          <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>       <fct>      <int>
 3 2016-10-01   CH00  0.0175    -0.000375             0         A              0
 4 2016-11-01   CH00 -0.0734    -0.0221               0         A              0
 5 2016-12-01   CH00 -0.0107     0.0183               0         A              0
 6 2017-01-01   CH00  0.0457     0.0642               1.9       A              1
 7 2017-02-01   CH00  0.0208     0.000647             0         A              1
 8 2017-03-01   CH00  0.0352     0.0364               0         A              1
...
15 2017-11-01  CH00  -0.0780496  0.0179349            0         A              1
16 2017-12-01  CH00   0.0688210 -0.0312227            0         A              1
17 2018-01-01  CH00  -0.0064685  0.0144049           -0.90      A              2
18 2018-02-01  CH00  -0.0997418  0.0119439            0         A              2
19 2018-03-01  CH00  -0.0203781 -0.0463974            0         A              2
...
45 2017-02-01  GB00   0.0056672  0.0006471            0         B+             1
46 2017-03-01  GB00   0.0028146  0.0364348            0         B+             1
47 2017-04-01  GB00   0.0366418  0.0144673            3.66      B+             2
48 2017-05-01  GB00   0.0745412  0.0242931            0         B+             2
49 2017-06-01  GB00   0.1555046  0.0222243            0         B+             2
...
```

I also tried it with the following way:

```
filter_lmco_<- within(testing, {
  event <- if_else(Rating_Change!=0,1,0)
  event <- ave(event, lag(ISIN), FUN=cumsum)
  event <- ifelse(Rating_Change != 0, event-1, event)
})
```

This had a similar output, however, it only takes the pre-windows and not the window "around" the event - at least I don't know how to formulate the syntax to have the windows around (-2:+2) the event.

Here I show you what I actually need:

```
   Date         ISIN    R        STOXX_Return   Rating_Change   Rating       event
   <date>       <fct>          <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>       <fct>      <int>
 3 2016-10-01   CH00  0.0175    -0.000375             0         A              0
 4 2016-11-01   CH00 -0.0734    -0.0221               0         A              1
 5 2016-12-01   CH00 -0.0107     0.0183               0         A              1
 6 2017-01-01   CH00  0.0457     0.0642               1.9       A              1
 7 2017-02-01   CH00  0.0208     0.000647             0         A              1
 8 2017-03-01   CH00  0.0352     0.0364               0         A              1
...
15 2017-11-01  CH00  -0.0780496  0.0179349            0         A              2
16 2017-12-01  CH00   0.0688210 -0.0312227            0         A              2
17 2018-01-01  CH00  -0.0064685  0.0144049           -0.90      A              2
18 2018-02-01  CH00  -0.0997418  0.0119439            0         A              2
19 2018-03-01  CH00  -0.0203781 -0.0463974            0         A              2
...
45 2017-02-01  GB00   0.0056672  0.0006471            0         B+             1
46 2017-03-01  GB00   0.0028146  0.0364348            0         B+             1
47 2017-04-01  GB00   0.0366418  0.0144673            3.66      B+             1
48 2017-05-01  GB00   0.0745412  0.0242931            0         B+             1
49 2017-06-01  GB00   0.1555046  0.0222243            0         B+             1
...
```

Has anyone an idea or approach how to solve this? All in all I have about 1600 events (plus pre and post window data). Any help and support is much appreciated!!
Thank you so much in advance. Please let me know if I shall clarify anything or give more details.

Comment: Hey @Jagge, thank you for reading into my issue. 
For each event I need the data pre and post event - this is exactly the point. If it only changes after row 17, the I always only have either pre-event or post-event, but not both at the same time, like "around" the event.  I need it this way, because I have to do some calculations with the pre-event-data and at the end match the calculation of the pre-event-data to all the relevant, pre AND post event, data points (for measuring abnormal returns of the event). Does this give you some clarifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this should do the trick

```
testing1 <- testing %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>%
  mutate(event=cumsum(lead(Rating_Change, 2)!=0 & !is.na(lead(Rating_Change, 2))))
```

it works in this case for some dummy data

```
tibble::tibble(
  Rating_Change = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,4)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(event=cumsum(dplyr::lead(Rating_Change, 2)!=0 & !is.na(dplyr::lead(Rating_Change, 2))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much- this is working perfectly now!! Really appreciating it!